# How can I am Implementation nebula gl in Angular with (deck gl, mapbox)?

Tags: angular, deck.gl

currently, I'm using deck.gl, mapbox, ScatterplotLayer in Angular and it works.
Im using this the package:

```html
import { ScatterplotLayer } from '@deck.gl/layers';
import { MapboxLayer } from '@deck.gl/mapbox';
import {DataFilterExtension} from '@deck.gl/extensions';
```

[point layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSs7Q.png)

Next step I want to add feature draws on the map like kepler.gl, like this:

[kepler gl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qsx6n.png)

Actually I'm very confused because in the reference I found only react-map-gl can implement for nebula.gl,
the question is, How can I Implementation nebula.gl with @deck.gl/mapbox and @deck.gl/layers ?

Thank you.